# Why am I getting "java.lang.NumberFormatException" when trying to convert this string into an integer?

Tags: java, parsing, url, encryption, random

I have been creating a Java program to encode a message received from the user. Just for some background into how it does this: It is supposed to get the input, split it into characters, then get a set of random numbers from Random.org (true random number generator) equal to the length of the message and then shift the characters of the input by their corresponding shift, or random number, then output the coded message and the shifts. So far I have gotten input, converted it into a string array, checked the quota (Random.org has a quota) and gotten the random numbers. I am getting this error when trying to output the converted shifts (from Strings gotten at the website to ints), I think it is because of a CRLF on the last number (I tried using a regex to fix this, but it didn't work). Here is my code:

public class Encryption_System {
    static String originalMessege;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the encryption system!");
    System.out.println("Type your messege below:");
    System.out.println("\nHere is your original messege: " + scan() + "\n");
    Encrypt code = new Encrypt();
    code.Messege(originalMessege);
    code.encryptMessege();

}

private static String scan() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    originalMessege = scan.nextLine();
    return originalMessege;
}
```

}

Then there is a second class, where my problem originates. My error comes from the last method (my attempted regex fix is commented out):

```
public class Encrypt {
    private String messege;
    private String[] characters;
    private URL quotaURL;
    private URLConnection conect;
    private InputStream quotaInput;
    private BufferedReader quotaReader;
    private int quota;
    private boolean go;
    private URL shiftsURL;
    private URLConnection conectShifts;
    private InputStream shiftsInput;
    private BufferedReader shiftsReader;
    private int count;
    private char[] shifts;
    private int[] shiftsInt;
    private String shiftsString;
    private String[] shiftsStrings;

    public void Messege(String x) {
        messege = x;
    }

    private String[] getCharacters() {
        characters = messege.split("(?!^)");
        return characters;
    }

    private boolean checkQuota() throws Exception {
        quotaURL = new URL("http://www.random.org/quota/?format=plain");
        conect = quotaURL.openConnection();
        quotaInput = conect.getInputStream();
        quotaReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(quotaInput));
        int quota = Integer.parseInt(quotaReader.readLine());
        if (quota >= getCharacters().length)
            go = true;
        else
            go = false;
        return go;
    }

    private char[] Shifts(String[] x1) throws Exception {
        String[] messegeArray = x1;
        count = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < x1.length; k++) {
            if (x1[k].equals(" ")) {
                continue;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
        shifts = new char[count * 3];
        if (checkQuota() == true) {
            shiftsURL = new URL("http://www.random.org/integers/?num=" + count
                    + "&min=1&max=27&col=" + count
                    + "&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new");
            conectShifts = shiftsURL.openConnection();
            shiftsInput = conectShifts.getInputStream();
            shiftsReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(shiftsInput));
            shiftsReader.read(shifts, 0, count * 3);
        }

        return shifts;
    }

    public void encryptMessege() throws Exception {
        char[] currentShifts = Shifts(getCharacters());
        shiftsString = new String(currentShifts);
        //  shiftsString.replace("[\t\r\n]", "");
        shiftsStrings = shiftsString.split("[(  )]");
        shiftsInt = new int[shiftsStrings.length];
        System.out.println("These are your shifts");
        for (int v = 0; v < shiftsInt.length; v++) {
            shiftsInt[v] = Integer.parseInt(shiftsStrings[v]);
            System.out.println(shiftsInt[v] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my output:

```
Welcome to the encryption system!
Type your messege below:
Hello

Here is your original messege: Hello

These are your shifts
3 
19 
12 
3 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12

Process completed.
```

I am just a Java beginner (first year high school comp sci), so thanks for any help!

Comment: please add full stack trace & reduce the amount of attached code

Comment: This is the stack trace. My IDE (Jcreator) output exactly what is above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is failing for me because:

```
shiftsStrings = shiftsString.split("[(  )]");
```

is not properly splitting the values.

EDIT:

Try This:

```
public void encryptMessege() throws Exception {
    List<Integer> shifts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(new String(Shifts(getCharacters())));
    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String token =st.nextToken();
        try{
            shifts.add(Integer.parseInt(token));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("did not parse: " + token);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("These are your shifts: " + shifts.toString());
}
```

Note there are a lot of things you should work on in your code.

1) Encapsulating functionality within methods.  It gets confusing when you keep all your variables as class level attributes.  If you pass them between methods using parameters, you gain easier to read code, and it's easier to test bits of your code.

2)  You should start method names with lower case letters.  This is common Java coding practice.

Comment: Would `shiftsStrings = shiftsString.split("  ");` be the proper way? It didn't change the output any.

Comment: I like that solution, it works well :) ... but I will figure that part out. Thanks :)

Comment: Disregard the ("but I will figure that part out later")

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be originating from here:

```
shiftsInt[v]= Integer.parseInt(shiftsStrings[v]);
```

And this fails when in the for loop value of `v` reaches `4`. Remove the expression from the for loop and see if every string in `shiftsStrings` *can* actually be parsed to `int`. Try executing this:

```
for(int v = 0; v < shiftsStrings.length; v++ ) {
    System.out.println(shiftsStrings[v]);
}
```

If there is something unexpected in the output, the next step would be to find out (and possibly remove) how that value found its place in the array.

Comment: I have, and it prints out the correct amount of numbers all separated by a tab and a CRLF at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it is due to non-number characters in the last number, then before putting it in parseInt use Replace on it with the characters that are non-number (you can use `\r`, `\n` and so on too).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char)

Trim is another useful method, it removes all leading and trailing whitespace.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: I thought so too, but when I used `replace("[\t\r\n]", "");` (and other variations on it) as well as trim, and it didn't work...

Comment: `replace("[\t\r\n]", "");` - **Java is not smart.** What about that method call tells Java that `[\t\r\n]` is a regex rather than a string?

Comment: You are correct, I was at first using `replaceAll("[\t\r\n]", "")` (with didn't work either) but I called replace instead with the same arguments.

Comment: If you're using a regex, you might need to double up on backslashes, e.g. `replaceAll("[\\t\\r\\n]", "")`. Not sure if it also applies in Java but I know it does in other languages.

Comment: I just learned about regexes yesterday, so I don't know about the validity of the statement, but I tried it, it compiled and executed, but gave me the same error.

Comment: A regex can be valid but not do what you want.

Comment: Okay, but I was simply saying that that aspect of syntax doesn't seem to make any difference, positive or negative. What would a "better" regex be? Like I said, I am very new to them.

Comment: A better regex is one that works ;) In some programming languages, you need to double backslashes before they reach the regex engine or the programming language interprets them as an escape, taking them away before the regex engine can interpret them as an escape. If you are new to regexes, you should always test regexes you come up with using a simple, obvious example before assuming they do what you think they do.